# Insert elements to Android Relative and Linear Layout

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am trying to insert `EditText` and `Button` to this code (layout to insert soft-keyboard) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_above="@+id/keyboard_view">
        <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/target"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <it.anddev.tutorial.CustomKeyboardView
        android:id="@+id/keyboard_view" android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"></it.anddev.tutorial.CustomKeyboardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

If I insert `EditText` and `Button` inside below `"@+id/target"` it has no effect. I do not know how to bring other elements under `EditText` (id=target).

Thanks for help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:orientation="vertical"` in your LinearLayout